# How do I split lines on a searched word or character using Python and keep the character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to append or put the remaining words into the next line when I have searched for the string or character already.
For example I have a file that has a paragraph like below:

```
/This is my first time doing this\ /I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\ /Trying so hard\ /Testing so hard\
```

I want to search for the `/` and have the result be like this:

```
/This is my first time doing this\
/I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\
/Trying so hard\
/Testing so hard\
```

So, whenever it sees a forwardslash `/` in line, it will move the remaining string or text in that line to the next line. I want to gather them into a list like format so that I can do further processing.

Comment: So you want to print a new line every time you encounter a space located between a backslash and a slash?

Comment: @barakmanos - Whenever it sees a forwardslash ( / ) in line, it will move the remaining string or text in that line to the next line.

Comment: Is there actually a blank line between each of your input and output lines? Or did you just put them into your question so that the lines would format properly?

Comment: Well, how about `for line in data.split('/'): print '/'+line`?

Comment: Also, do you just want to print these lines, or are you trying to gather them into a list of lines that you can do further processing on?

Comment: @barakmanos - so would it be like this? 
       with open("SQAETL-Logidfn-SPEEDTEST.txt", "r+"), open('tes5.txt', 'w') as : f 
             for line in f.split('/'): 
                 f.write(line)??

Comment: @PM2Ring I want to gather them into a list like format so that I can do further processing on.

Comment: @PM2Ring Just so it would look clean then when it looks cleaner I'll write it in a new text file.

Comment: So are those blank lines supposed to be there, or not?

Comment: @PM2Ring they are not. I just cant format my question properly. 
first line : 1st sentence
second line: 2nd sentence

Comment: Hi, I Cleaned up the question formatting a bit.  I also incorporated your comments.  For future questions, you can indent by 4 spaces, anything you want to preserve the formatting on.  You can use the backtick to surround things that are code like, eg: `this`. One way to see how the formatting was done, is to select the edit link on this post and then inspect how it looks in the editor.  These changes hopefully make it easier for someone else to use this information later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this again. By replacing the character to next line

```
def sample():
    with open(r'sample.txt', 'r') as infile, open(r'sample2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            data = infile.read()
            data = data.replace("/","\n") 
            outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: Your code won't create the correct output: Karl wants to keep those slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to split up your text into a list of lines.

```
data = r'''/This is my first time doing this\ /I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\ /Trying so hard\ /Testing so hard\
'''

print(data)
print('- ' * 20)

# Put text after `/` onto a new line
data = data.replace('/', '\n/')

# Split text up into a list of lines
lines = data.splitlines()

# Remove leading and trailing whitespace from each line
lines = [s.strip() for s in lines]

# Get rid of empty lines
lines = [s for s in lines if s]

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

**output**

```
/This is my first time doing this\ /I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\ /Trying so hard\ /Testing so hard\

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
/This is my first time doing this\
/I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\
/Trying so hard\
/Testing so hard\
```

---

To make sure that each line has *exactly* the contents that we want we can print its representation:

```
# show the representation of each line
for line in lines:
    print(repr(line))
```

**output**

```
'/This is my first time doing this\\'
'/I am trying to append this line\\'
"/I can't seem to find the solution\\"
'/Trying so hard\\'
'/Testing so hard\\'
```

Note that a single backslash is shown as a pair of backslashes in the representation. Similarly, to put a backslash into a normal Python string literal you need to use two backslashes, eg

```
s = 'One backslash \\ here'
```

I didn't need to do that in the `data` string literal because I used a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

---

To read `data` from a text file instead of using a string literal, you just need to use the file `.read` method, like this:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
print(data)
```

**output**

```
/This is my first time doing this\ /I am trying to append this line\
/I can't seem to find the solution\ /Trying so hard\ /Testing so hard\
```

---

When you've finished processing the `lines` list and wish to save it to a new file, the simplest way is to pass a file argument to print. Eg,

```
with open('sample3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines: 
        print(line, file=outfile)
```

I should also mention that to use the `print` *function* in Python 2 instead of the `print` *statement*, then you need to import it. To do that, put this line at the top of the script, before other imports:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Actually, it's a good idea to tell the interpreter to use Python 3 style division as well:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
```

Comment: How if I want to start this with opening a file? with open('test.txt') as data: ??

Comment: one last, for line in lines:
    print(line) how can I print it in another text file? line | tee sample3.txt???

Comment: @KarlGuevarra I just remembered that you're using Python 2. So I've added some important info about using the `print` function in Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered doing this, for example you have a paragraph that the second sentence has a charcter of '/'.

```
def sampleFunction():

    text = "/"
    newText = "\n"

    x = fileinput.input(files ="log.txt", inplace=1)
    for line in x:
        if text in line:
            line = newText
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

So that the line that starts with the '/' will be in next line.

Comment: It just made my text file blank because if the line has the "/" it turns it into a next line which is blank

Comment: or create a function that will replace the character '/' to '\n'

Comment: I'm using the slahes as my delimiter so readers can easily distinguish the start and end